# Scroll through shell history based on command or stub/stem?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, command-history

Please forgive my ignorance.... I have a history of commands in Bash on OS X and Linux. At times, I want to go back to an item based on the command. For example, suppose I previously entered:

```
make distclean && make dist && cp *.diff *.tar.gz ../
```

Then, suppose I have tens or hundreds of commands following it in history.

How can I type `make` and then use, say, the up arrow (***`↑`***) or control and up arrow (***`CTRL`*** ***`↑`***) to go back to that command in history?

The "stub" or "stem" means I only type "ma", and not "make".

I work in Bash on both Linux and OS X, so I'd be interested in both operating systems.

Comment: You want to do: `Ctrl-R`, type `make` and then hit `Ctrl-R` until you find the make command you want to re-do.

Comment: @Glenn - you should answer. I just verified CTRL+R works on both. (Its not as elegant as I would like, but it works well. For some reason, I thought I could type `make` and the `CTRL` + `↑`).

Comment: The [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) does this /very/ well, but it is not bash. I'd recommend taking a some time to read the bash manual and learn the various history mechanisms

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to `Ctrl-R`, you can use the history command and pipe it to `grep` for a specific command.

```
$ history | grep vi 
    7  vi /etc/shells
    8  sudo vi /etc/shells
```

From there, you can see the history number, and can run that command again using `!number`.

```
$ !8
sudo vi /etc/shells
Password:
```

And I believe as long as you don't fill up or clean out the command history, that number should remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here are few useful tricks which help you to repeat the command based on previous commands (apart of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>):

- use `!name` to repeat last command starting with name, e.g.:

  ```
  !make
  ```
- to repeat command (e.g. with `sudo`), use:

  ```
  sudo !!
  ```
- to repeat argument, use `!$`:

  ```
  ls /usr/local/bin
  cd  !$
  ```
- to edit the file from the last argument, use `!^`:

  ```
   cp /etc/hosts hosts.bak
   vim !^
  ```

See more at: [How To Use Bash History to Improve Your Command-Line Productivity](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44997/how-to-use-bash-history-to-improve-your-command-line-productivity/)

Also see: [What are your favorite command line features or tricks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67/21471) at Unix SE

---

As a side-note, if you're making typos too often, the is an app for that:

- [The Fuck - Magnificent app which corrects your previous console command](https://github.com/nvbn/thefuck) :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `readline` (not `bash`) feature that does exactly that. Add :

```
"\e[A":history-search-backward
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

to your `.inputrc` file.
Unlike `Ctrl-r` it only matches on the prefix.
See [The most important command-line tip - incremental history searching with .inputrc](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/the-most-important-command-line-tip-incremental-history-searching-with-inputrc/) for more details.

Comment: That looks promising (assuming ***`"\e[A"`*** is like ***`CTRL`*** + ***`↑`***). Unfortunately, I don't have an `.inputrc` on either OS X or Linux. When I added it to `.bash_profile` on OS X (and then source'd it), it resulted in ***`-bash: \e[A:: command not found`***.

Comment: `readline` is the library used by `bash` to handle the history, (unless the `--noediting`  option is used). It has it's own configuration file, usually `~/.inputrc` (user), `/etc/inputrc` (global) or the file declared in the `INPUTRC` variable. There is a whole section about `readline` in the `bash` man page. There is quite a few interesting configuration options